# How can $\frac{1+1+1+\ldots}{2+2+2+\ldots} be \frac{(1+1)+(1+1)+\ldots}{2+2+2+\ldots} = 1$?

Tags: calculus

$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1+1+1+\ldots}{2+2+2+\ldots} = \frac{(1+1)+(1+1)+\ldots}{2+2+2+\ldots} =  1$ says user Karolis Juodelė.
Why does it get 7 votes up for this comment? I guess that 1/2 is not 1. See: [Whats infinity divided by infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181304/whats-infinity-divided-by-infinity)

Comment: This involves some playing fast and loose with limit processes that is not in-bounds.

Comment: And you don't need to mention the limit explicitly anywhere?

Comment: An infinite sum is automatically a limit process.

Comment: That user was doing a proof by contradiction. She is saying, assume that this division is valid. Then it comes out to both 1/2 and 1. That is a contradiction and therefore the division is invalid.

Comment: It wasn't an answer. it was a comment. Upvoting comments isn't the same as upvoting an answer.

Comment: There is a [solid chance](http://www.gpeters.com/names/baby-names.php?name=Karolis) that Karolis Juodele be a he and not a she.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted [that comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181304/whats-infinity-divided-by-infinity#comment417854_181304) because it appeared to me that it was a very clear and succinct demonstration of *exactly* why we can't handle expressions like $$\frac{1+1+1+\cdots}{2+2+2+\cdots}$$ the same way we can handle finite expressions.  The original question asked why $\infty\over\infty$ is not simply taken to be 1; Karolis's answer shows why we do not.

Comment: I guess this can't be correct if we have an equal amount of 1's and 2's?: $\frac{1+1+1+\ldots}{2+2+2+\ldots} = \frac{(1+1)+(1+1)+\ldots}{2+2+2+\ldots}$

Comment: It isn't correct regardless. You can't handle expressions like that the same way you handle finite expressions, and you can't understand them in the same way either.

Comment: If the answer isn't 1/2, Then, why should this answer by Chindea be correct? $$ \frac{1 + 1 + \cdots}{2 + 2 + \cdots} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{2n} = \frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: Filip **did not** say that it was equal to $\frac12$. He said that even if one were to adopt a certain obvious-seeming rule for assigning values infinite quotients, one would *still* get inconsistent results.