# How does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n^2} 1$ result into 1+3+5...

Tags: calculus

How can $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n^2} 1$ result into 1+3+5...? Why odd numbers?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ doesn't "result" in $1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots$.  The limit doesn't exist.

Comment: I mean, probably you are just talking about the partial sums, but if that's the case I don't understand why you put a limit sign there.

Comment: @Goos as in Peter's context: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396810/explain-the-1-2-3-in-frac1-1-1-cdots1-2-3-cdots-lim

Comment: Peter's context involves a limit of ratios of partial sums, not a ratio of limits of partial sums.

Comment: @user8005 I think that 1+3+5.. expresion is understood to be a limit

Answer (score 3):

Hoo boy. You're in for a treat; this theorem was known to Pythagoras and his disciples.

> Theorem: The sum of the first $n$ odd numbers is equal to $n^2$.

Proof: By picture.

[image: Picture proof for theorem]

The original image is part of a page containing two proofs of this identity: http://www.9math.com/book/sum-first-n-odd-natural-numbers. It is not mine.

Comment: I like this proof, essentially is the telescopic sum argument $\sum (2k-1)=\sum [k^2-(k-1)^2]=n^2$

Comment: AoPS has another picture, not exactly this one: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Proofs_without_words.

Comment: Yeah I know them, but this is my favorite.

Answer (score 2):

$$1+3+5+\ldots+(2n-1)=\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)=\sum_{k=1}^n [k^2-(k-1)^2]=n^2-0^2=n^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} 1$$

Comment: Does this definition have a name? Your response on Goos's the limit doesn't exist?

Comment: @user8005 I don't know, its just a variant of this sum http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: @GastónBurrull Per your comment, regularization of divergent sums is a very tangential topic; I feel that bringing it up without clarifying the meaning of the original situation (see my comment above) with limits could be derailing.

Comment: @anon I can only answer about partial sums, I think what OP means has nothing to do with the phenomenon to quantify divergent sums as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%E2%88%92_2_%2B_3_%E2%88%92_4_%2B_%C2%B7_%C2%B7_%C2%B7 I think I'm ignorant about this other topic

Answer (score 0):

Note that the definition of summation 
$
\sum_{k=1}^m a_k
$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^m a_k=a_1 +a_2+ \ldots +a_m.
$$
So, for eachpositive integer $n$, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} 1=\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} (1+0k)=1+ 1+\ldots +1(n^2 {\rm times})=n^2.
$$
On the other hand, for the same integer $n$, we have
$$
{\rm sum\,\, of \,\,n-positive\,\, odd \,\,numbers}(=1+3+5+ \ldots+ (2n-1))=n^2.
$$
Thus, we can write
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} 1=1=3+5+\ldots+(2n-1) \tag 1
$$
Letting $n\to \infty$ in (1) we get the asked expression.

Comment: Wow, $1=1+0k$, I never saw before such a trick, probably would help me working with hard sums