# Infinity divided by infinity

Tags: limits

We know that:

> $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\infty}{\infty} = \text{indeterminate}$

And that:

> $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{n} = 1$

How can I easily explain the difference to first-year university students?

Comment: Just explain that $n\ne\infty$, all the more so as $\infty$ is but a metaphor.

Comment: The top should read $\frac{\infty}{\infty}=$ indeterminate. It makes no sense to divide infinities as it is not a number; the concept of a limit (which is used in the second one) allows us to treat infinities and the like with more precision. As well as this saying that the limit of a function approaches a value is definitely not the same as saying the function is equal to that value evaluated at that point

Comment: But $\text {lim}_{n \to \infty} n = \infty$ is a correct expression (it says that there is **no** number that is the limit of the sequence $\{ n \}$) while $\text {lim}_{n \to \infty}  \infty$  makes no sense.

Comment: Related: [What is infinity divided by infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181304/what-is-infinity-divided-by-infinity)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You write

> We know that:
>   $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\infty}{\infty} = indeterminate$

but I'd say that we don't know that at all. (Indeed, it makes no sense).

What we *do* know is that if 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = \infty
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n) = \infty
$$
then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} 
$$
cannot be directly computed with a quotient rule.

I hate to say this, but I think your problem is not with "explaining this to first-year university students", but rather with knowing and understanding the main theorems yourself before trying to explain them to others.

Comment: By "we know that" I indeed meant what you explained in more details.

Comment: Teaching mathematics well involves (among many other things) saying the true stuff and avoiding the nonsense pretty conscientiously, lest your students start imitating you and thinking that they're saying something true. When you start by asserting nonsense, you're headed down a bad path, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for your very valuable input.

Comment: I strongly agree with this answer. $\infty/\infty$ is an advanced shorthand that shouldn’t be shown to first year students.

Answer (score 0):

I may first give an example : finding limit 
$$  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1+x}{x} $$

When we use straightforward approach, we get
$$ \frac{\infty+1}{\infty}  =    \frac{\infty}{\infty} $$
In the process of investigating a limit, we know that both the numerator and denominator are going to infinity.. but we dont know the **behaviour** of each dynamics. But if we investigate further we get : $$ 1 + \frac{1}{x} $$
Some other examples :

1. Numerator might get larger than denomenator exactly $m$ times. The limit will be $m$ : for example $\lim \frac{mx}{x}$. Or the opposite : for example $\lim \frac{x}{mx}$
2. The numerator gets way too large than denominator : $\lim \frac{x^2}{x}$ , the limit is clearly $\infty$. Or the opposite : $\lim \frac{x}{x^2}$.

Thanks.