# Why does the limit of ${\left( {{1 \over 2}} \right)^n}$ tend to one and not zero?

Tags: limits

Take for example the following: $${\left( {{1 \over 2}} \right)^n}$$ as n tends to infinity, the denominator tends to infinity, while the numerator stays the same (i.e. one).  I thought $$\left( {{1 \over \infty }} \right) = 0$$  Yet Wikipedia says it equals one?
[Converging Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

Comment: Your expression does tend to zero.  It's the sum of all the terms along the way that converges to 1.

Comment: Oh, I see the difference now.  But if one divided by infinity equals zero, then infinity multiplied by zero is one???

Comment: That's a little above my pay grade, but you can check this out.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28940/why-is-infinity-multiplied-by-zero-not-an-easy-zero-answer

Comment: @MichaelLee notice that multiplying the equation by $a\in\mathbb{R}$ you get that $0\cdot\infty=a$ but $a$ can be any real number hence limit of form $\infty\cdot 0$ can be any value.

Comment: @kingW3 I see and the numerator can be any other real number and infinity is not a real number.

Comment: Regarding the title: the *sequence* tends to zero, the limit *equals* zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The summands $\frac1{2^n}$ tend to zero indeed. But the Wikipedia page you reference is about the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2^n}$.

Comment: And of course, an infinite series can't possibly converge if the summand doesn't tend to zero!