# Show that product of null-set is again a null-set

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

This is question 13.2 in "Measures, Integrals and Martingales" by R.L. Schilling. The answer can be found [here](http://www.motapa.de/measures_integrals_and_martingales/solutions13-24.pdf). I don't understand why they use an exhausting sequence rather than apply the definition of the product measure directly.

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, $(Y,\mathcal{B},\nu)$ be two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. Show that $A \times N$, where $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $N \in \mathcal{B}$, $\nu(N) = 0$, is a $\mu \times \nu$ - null set.

Now in the answer, they take two exhausting sequences and by taking the intersection of $A$ and $N$ with these sequences the proposition is proven. I would understand this if the product measure was defined only on those sequences, but it is defined as (theorem 13.5):

$\rho: \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B} \to [0,\infty]$, $\rho(A \times B) := \mu(A)\nu(B)$.

Why can't we just say $\rho(A \times N) = \mu(A)\nu(N) = \mu(A) 0 = 0$ ?

Comment: If "we just say that" then we are also saying that $\infty.0=0$. Care is needed. Maybe you should check what is said about product measures uptil that stage of the book.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I was thinking that might be the problem. However, it is explicitly said in a previous chapter (ch 8, on the extended real line) that $0*(\infty) = 0$. This is not an expression that we safely use in general then? Chapter 13 is the first chapter on product spaces btw. Sorry if this is a bit elementary.

Comment: I have no example at hand where the equality "goes wrong" and am not eager to explore the book. Maybe someone else will help you with this. Good luck!

Comment: you're right, I can google that much ;) [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28940/why-is-infinity-multiplied-by-zero-not-an-easy-zero-answer) gives some insight. Not really used to working with infinity yet... Let me know if this question is useless and I should remove it.

Comment: For $A$ is of infinity measure, use the fact that $A$ is $\sigma$-finite and find a sequence of set with finite measure to approach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mu(A)<\infty$, you are right. It needs to prove the case for $\mu(A)=\infty$.

Since $\mu$ is $σ$-finite, there is a sequence of sets $O_n$ with finite measure, i.e. $\mu(O_n)<\infty$ such that
$$
O_1\subset O_2\subset \cdots\subset O_n\subset \cdots\quad\text{and }\quad 
A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} O_n
$$
By monotone class theorem in measure theory 
$$
\mu (A)=\mu \left ( \bigcup _{n=1}^{\infty} O_n\right )=\lim _{n\to \infty }\mu (O_n)
$$ 
So we have
$$
\rho(A \times N) = \rho\left ( \bigcup _{n=1}^{\infty} O_n\times N\right ) = \lim _{n\to \infty }\rho (O_n\times N)=\lim _{n\to \infty }\mu (O_n)\nu(N) =  0
$$