# When is it allowed to multiply with zero in algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Consider the example:

$$\frac{7}{x} = 0$$

If we multiply both sides by $x$ we get

$$7 = 0$$

which obviously is wrong.

However with the equation

$$\frac{7x^2 - 67x +126}{x(x-2)(x-3)} = 0$$

You can multiply by zero and get

$$7x^2 -67x + 126 = 0$$

I think it is because there are still $x$'s remaining in the expression. However what is the exact rule when it is allowed to multiply by zero and when it is not...

Comment: In your first example, $x$ would have to approach infinity for it to be true. However, you can not just say $\infty\times{0}=0$ as such an equation is not true (see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28940/why-is-infty-cdot-0-not-clearly-equal-to-0).

Comment: The equation 7/x =0 has no solution.

Comment: $\dfrac 7x=0$ is obviously wrong as well.

Comment: @YvesDaoust To be precise: $7/x=0$ can't be neither true nor false since it's not a *statement* but a *statement form* instead.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: right, see my answer.

Comment: For purposes of equivalent equations, if you multiply any equation by 0 on both sides, you get a tautology, indicating all values are solutions, even if the original had no solutions. So I assert that multiplying both sides by zero does not create an equivlant equation. Agreed?(even if slightly off topic, but this is what I was seeking to confirm...)Agreed? 5w=5w multiply by 0 and you get 0=0, always true, thus w=any complex # 5x=5x+1 has no solutions. multipying by x-x gets you 5x^2-5x^2=5x^2-5x^2+x-x which gets you 0 = 0 so "always true for any complex # x? Not so! So, for purposes of equiva

Answer (score 1):

An equation of the form $$\frac{f(x)}{x} =g(x)$$ can only make sense when $x\ne 0$. You’re free to multiply with $x$ here. However, for an equation of the form $$f(x)=g(x) $$ You can only *divide* by $x$ if you know that $x\ne 0$. Note that there is no restriction on multiplying here, too. As for your first equation, $$\frac 7x=0$$ has no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply $0$ both side of an eauality anytime. But here nowhere we are multiplying $0$ both side.
Both are equations in $x$. For the first one if we assume there is some nonzero $x$ satisfying $\dfrac 7x=0$ then we arrive at a contradiction so there is no such $x$.

For the second one again let there exists $x$ such that $x(x-2)(x-3)$ is nonzero and $$\dfrac{7x^2-67x+126}{x(x-2)(x-3)}=0.$$ Then multiplying $x(x-2)(x-3)$ both side we get $7x^2-67x+126=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In your first case, $$\frac 7 x = 0$$ doesn't have a solution. This is because $$\frac yx$$ is only equal to 0 if $$y = 0$$ If x=0 the expression is undefined.

In your second case we can deduce that, as the fraction is equal to 0, the numerator must be equal to 0. This gives us $$7x^2 - 67x + 126 = 0$$ which can then be solved.

Comment: Why are you introducing y?

Comment: y is just a variable I used to represent the numerator of a fraction.

Comment: This is the sort of answer I would have given. In the case of the two equations and the implication (fraction=0) $\Rightarrow$ (polynomial=0), you just look at the fraction, and say “How can this fraction be zero? Only when the denominator is zero!” and proceed from there. Plus one.

Answer (score 1):

Though your question shows something different, you can always "multiply by zero" the members of an equation, *provided they have a defined value*.

1. $\dfrac 7x=0\implies0=0$ provided $x\ne0$ (otherwise the LHS is not defined).
2. $\dfrac{7x^2 - 67x +126}{x(x-2)(x-3)} = 0\implies0=0$ provided $x\notin\{0,2,3\}$ (otherwise the LHS is not defined).

---

What you should have asked instead is "is it allowed to multiply by *nonzero* in algebra", and the answer is also yes (provided the members have a defined value).

1. $\dfrac 7x=0\land x\ne0\implies 7=0$ proves that there is no suitable $x$.
2. $\dfrac{7x^2 - 67x +126}{x(x-2)(x-3)} = 0\land x\notin\{0,2,3\}\implies 7x^2 - 67x +126=0\\\implies x=\dfrac{18}7\lor x=7$.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example there is no solution to equation, and in you second equation there can be a solution. There is no rule, you can do that anytime you want.

Comment: So I can multiply by zero everytime I want, but it is not necessarily useful..I.e. in case one it isn't but in case two it is...

Comment: yes, that is what I mean.